# WPF Commands - Doing it with no code-behind

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvp, command

I'm building a simple data entry app in WPF form using the MVVM pattern. Each form has a presenter object that exposes all the data etc. I'd like to use WPF Commands for enabling and disabling Edit/Save/Delete buttons and menu options.

My problem is that this approach seems to require me to add lots of code to the code-behind. I'm trying to keep my presentation layer as thin as possible so I'd much rather this code/logic was inside my presenter (or ViewModel) class rather than in code-behind. Can anyone suggest a way to achieve the same thing without code-behind?

My XAML looks a bit like this:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding 
        Command="ApplicationCommands.Save"
        CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"
        Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"
    />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

and my code-behind looks a bit like this:

```
private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = (
        _presenter.SelectedStore != null &&
        _presenter.SelectedStore.IsValid);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) design pattern aims at achieving exactly that goal, and Josh Smith's [excellent article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) explains how to apply it.

For commands you can use the `RelayCommand` class described in the article.

Since you already have a presenter object, you can let that class expose an `ICommand` property that implements the desired logic, and then bind the XAML to that command. It's all explained in the article.

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifically looking at trying to bind a command in the ViewModel to one of the application commands in XAML, you have to build the infrastructure to do so yourself.  I walk though doing that [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36254653/548304) which then allows you to do something like this:

```xml
<local:RoutedCommandHandlers.Commands>
  <local:RoutedCommandHandler RoutedCommand="ApplicationCommands.Save" 
                              Command="{Binding TheSaveCommand}" />
</local:RoutedCommandHandlers.Commands>
```